# Avoid Infinity value when using Math.pow and comparision with loops

Tags: javascript, loops, math, pow

When I do `Math.pow(3, num)/num`, it is giving me the value if `Infinity` and when I do `modulus` of that with `2` it is giving me `NaN`. I understand NaN is due to Infinity. I am using `300530164787` as the num and am expecting to do a modulus on the above formulae.

Any way I can avoid this?

`Math.pow(3, num)/num = Infinity`
`(Math.pow(3, num)/num)%2 = NaN`

Second which is faster?

1. `Math.pow(3, num)` OR
2. `for` loop for 3x3x....

Comment: that is a huge number 3^300530164787 far bigger than the number of atoms in the universe which is  about 10e80. `Math.pow` should be faster

Comment: Right, you're doing math with numbers that cannot be represented with 64-bit binary floating point.

Comment: What do you mean avoid? What's the purpose of taking mod 2 in your code?

Comment: When `3n**300530164787n` results in an "*Uncaught RangeError: Maximum BigInt size exceeded*", you know that you're doing something weird.

Comment: Might take a look here: https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/binary-exp.html#implementation

Comment: OK I'm no math whiz, but `(3^x) % 2` is the same as `(3 % 2) ^ x`which is `1^x` which is `1`, and `1/x` when `x` is super huge is basically zero.

Comment: I thought about that as well, unfortunately it's `((3**n) / n) % 2` not `((3**n) % 2) / n`

Comment: Maybe computers won't help you with this problem. Try https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ITgoldman Yes, maths does help :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is a mathematical trick we can apply to allow us using a [modular exponentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) algorithm:

```
(a/b) % 2 ≡ (a % 2b) / b
```

In your case, that will be computing `3**num % (2*num)` using modular exponentiation, without loosing considerable `number` precision on large `num` values (> 10) or overflowing `bigint` memory for huge `num` values (> 1e9). Then you just need to divide by `num` to get your result.

```js
function modularPow(base, exponent, modulus) {
    if (modulus == 1n) return 0n;
    let result = 1n;
    base = base % modulus;
    for (; exponent; exponent >>= 1n) {
        if (exponent & 1n) result = (result * base) % modulus;
        base = (base * base) % modulus;
    }
    return result;
}

const num = 300530164787n;
console.log(Number(modularPow(3n, num, 2n*num)) / Number(num));
```

Comment: Yea I knew it would be something like that :)

Comment: Yes, this should solve the problem. `(Math.pow(3, num) - 3)/num`. The above throws error on `Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions` during negation.

Comment: this will be grossly wrong `if (exponent & 1n) result = ((result * base) -base) % modulus;` will grossly going wrong.  Second, if I wish to get the `(Math.pow(3, num) - 3)/num` the values will fail with Infinity again since there will be no modulus

Comment: @Gary Where's that `-3` coming from? That's nowhere in your question. If you want to solve a different exercise, please ask a new question about it.

Comment: let us say i am using 10 as the base. when i am using `Math.pow(10, 11)-10/11` / `Math.pow(10, 13)-10/13`, this will fail. Second `var value = (Math.pow(3, num)/num)` and `value%2` then this is what I am trying to achieve. the priority order of operands will fail here.

Comment: second, would `console.log(Number(modularPow(3n, num, 1n*num)) / Number(num));` also work? This way was to check if that is a number is a integer and not a decimal. My results are varing.

Comment: third, if i use an operand in between like `var value = (Math.pow(3,numm)-3)/numm` the above way fails miserably. the issue is the `bigint limit` gets exceeded during such operation. so invariably `value%2` or `value%1` will fail invariably.

Comment: You may want to [clarify your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74339464/edit) how to deal with decimals - as currently stated, you seem to want to compute the decimal remainder. Maybe post some expected result values for smaller inputs.

Comment: end of the day `Math.pow(somevalue, numm) >> infinity` and `Math.pow(somevalue, numm) (somecalculation) >> infinity`calculation is something i definitely wish to break here.

Comment: My answer already shows how not to exceed the limits of the calculation. If your actual formula is different and also includes a subtraction, you apply a similar equivalence where `(a - b) mod n ≡ (a mod n - b) mod n` to still make use of modular exponentiation.

Comment: No. `third, if i use an operand in between like` is what i meant. what did you mean by `(a - b) mod n ≡ (a mod n - b) mod n`. i am missing you here if you can help. :) say i am using `var val = Math.pow(3, num); val = val * 2; val = val/num; console.log(val)` or `var val = Math.pow(3, num); val = val - 3; val = val/num; console.log(val)`, what part of implementation changes. i am bounced by the fact that `(a/b) % 2 ≡ (a % 2b) / b` is not `(a/b) % 1 ≡ (a % 1b) / b` and is not `((a-x)/b) % 2 ≡ ((a-x) % 2b) / b` and is not `((a-x)/b) % 1 ≡ ((a-x) % 1b) / b`

Comment: My results are somehow varing based n above due to this `if (modulus == 1n) return 0n;` especially when i have `((a-x)/b) % 1 ≡ ((a-x) % 1b) / b`. What changes should i be doing in these cases where `a = Math.pow(x, num)`. I also tried using this but it also fails with limit errors. https://github.com/peterolson/BigRational.js

Comment: Where in `((3**num) * 2) / num` or `((3**num) - 3) / num` did you loose the modulo operation?

Comment: No I did not. First, Let us say the mod operation is 3. The logic works. But if the mod is 1 then the logic does not work. I may wish to capture the decimals. Second, if I have a operation after pow then the mod will fail. Say `a = math.pow(Xn, y); ((a-X) % 1y) / y` will fail due to this `if (modulus == 1n) return 0n;` third, a-X will fail if I use a X as an integer since a comes with `n` format and not int format. I cannot do 1 + 1n in js. it will fail.

Comment: Let us say I have five formulaes 1. `Math.pow(x, num)/num`  , 2.  `(Math.pow(x, num)/num)%2` , 3.  `((Math.pow(x, num) -x)/num)%2` , 4. `(Math.pow(x, num)/num)%1` , 5.  `((Math.pow(x, num) - x)/num)%1`. 4, 5 will fail with `0n`. Second, 3 will fail due to `int + intN (3+3n)` issue. 2 will work with approx values only with mod which is greater than 2

Comment: Another complexity `((Math.pow(x, num) * x) / num) % z`, things may show variance.

Comment: Like I explained `Math.pow(x, num) = Infinity` in  `Math.pow(3, num)/num = Infinity` in the question - this remains the main issue due to bigint limit. Not just due to an issue of mod

Comment: You cannot compute `x ** n` for large values without hitting the limits. What you *can* compute is `(x ** n) % m`. You need to convert any formula that does exponentiation to do modular exponentiation instead.

Comment: And yes, of course you need to compute bigints as `3n + 3n` instead of `3 + 3n`

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not well-defined. You just ask:

> **Any way** I can avoid this?

Yes, there are many ways you can avoid this. One way to "avoid getting NaN's", is described below...

The mod 2 yields a recursive result (for integer inputs) for odd or even numbers, returning only 1 or 0, and the function `(3^x)/x>1` for any integer `x>0`, you don't really care about how large is the first fraction, the only thing you care is whether it's even or odd... So why don't you define a large number (less than the necessary to get the `Infinity`), and mod the `num`, say

```
// Do your thing
var numm = num%1000;
// this should preserve parity,
// you can use any power of 10
(Math.pow(3, numm)/numm)%2
```

Comment: The result is a the remainder of a fraction, not an integer remainder. If it was, the question would be trivial indeed…

Comment: Simple counterexample, with `10` as the power of ten: `((3**11)/11)%2` is `0.2727272727279342…`, whereas `((3**1)/1)%2` is `1`.

Comment: i am unsure if this works cleanly. try these out. It still fails with biint memeory exception in js. `var numm = 300530164787%1000;console.log((Math.pow(3, numm)/numm)%1) ` and `var numm = 300530164787%1000;console.log((Math.pow(3, numm)/numm)%2)`

Comment: "anyway I can avoid this" -- my answer avoids getting `NaN`'s

Comment: that fact that you don't like my answer, doesn't make it wrong, since the OP did not specify what is the "correct" way that they are looking for... my answer solves the problem in "one way", since I get rid of the NaN's